# Error loading solr config from solrconfig.xml

Tags: linux, solr, lucene, jetty

I'm using solr 5.2.1 with jetty.In my logs(solr.log) there's an error with 
"org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer; Error creating core [dosweb]: Could not load conf for core project : Error loading solr config from solrconfig.xml" title
,and I understand it's because of misconfigured in solr version,and it is showing me this exception:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal parameter 'termIndexInterval'

,what I should do to fix it.
thanks alot.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Also verify your "conf" folder exists and contains all the necessary files such as solrconfig.xml, schema.xml, and others.

Comment: @NathanHall  it's misconfigured for 5.2.1 ,and it is showing this exception: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal parameter 'termIndexInterval'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough data.

It seems like your core is misconfigured for 5.2.1

I'd suggest that you try first with a reference configuration core, or a reference empty core, make sure that works, and then merge the config from the dosWeb core to the newly created core in steps.

This way you will find the part of the configuration that causes the issue.

EDIT -

After you added information (still not enough - a snippet of the offending configuration would have been good) I've been able to track down the bug that refers to the issue you get.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6560

Essentially - the configuration for termIndexInterval is now not only deprecated, but can't be done in a standard way at all. From what I understand from the bug, It's also not needed anymore.

Comment: yes it's misconfigured for 5.2.1 ,and it is showing this exception: 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal parameter 'termIndexInterval'